# How can I change Login Name in SQL Server Profiler from Domain/Username to NTAuthority/IUSR

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012, sql-server-profiler

We have 3 database with the same settings, configurations and permission etc. But when I run SQL SERVER PROFILER, the 2 database Login Name is NTAuthority/IUSR which is what I wanted but the last database Login Name is Domain/Username. How can I change the Login Name from Domain/UserName to NTAuthority/IUSR?

These 3 dabatabase is running on SQL Server 2012 SP4 ofcourse with the same instance.

They have the same:
 -web.config (ofcourse different database name in connection string)
 -IIS settings (windows authentication with impersonation enabled)
 -Permission (database login)

I want the LoginName in SQL Server Profiler to be NTAuthority/IUSR instead of Domain/Username.

Comment: all of three db is on  one SQL Server instance???

Comment: yes sir all of the 3 db are on the same instance